# I have an issue with nav bar. The text i add, defaults into next line when i resize it. need the text to shrink when i resize. Thanks

Tags: html, css

[What I want it to look like, even in mobile view (resized)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJDpu.png)

[What it looks like when shrunk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsKrU.png)

I have used padding-left:10px to create a space between text here.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

.container span {
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Home</span>
  <span>Awards</span>
  <span>Essay</span>
  <span>Impact Made</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. helped me. I'm self-thought. I'm learning through google. so, I'm rustic. And, thanks.

Comment: You will be an expert in no time keep practicing. Even I am self taught :)